# Airflow: how to force fail bash operator

Tags: python, airflow

I am running a series of python scripts (ex: script1.py, script2.py) in a script (ex: do_stuff.sh) which I am running using the airflow BashOperator. I was wondering if there was a way I could fail the BashOperator from within a python script if a specific condition is not met? I do not need the script itself to fail per say just the BashOperator so I can trigger a clean_up task.

script1.py:

```
def main(x)
    if x == 0:
        raise ValueError('BashOperator FAILS')
    else:
        print x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import plac
    plac.call(main)
```

Sorry if my question is basic, I am still a newbie at airflow/scripting.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Is there any reason you aren't using a PythonOperator rather than the BashOperator?

Comment: I was using Bash Operator because I wanted to use python scripts rather than defining the python modules in the dag.py itself. Does that reasoning make sense?

Comment: I can sort of see where you're coming from, but I'm not sure I'd do it like that. A python operator can be an arbitrary python callable which can be defined anywhere in your code base ie in a separate module for example. So you don't need to define it in the `dag.py`, you can define it in a different file. If that's not completely familiar to you, check out the documentation here: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), in particular section 6.4.

Comment: @amadorschulze92 have you maybe found a solution which you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bash command you should be able to just do:

```
exit 123
```

In this case you are exiting with error code 123, but you could use whatever error code you want.

EDIT:

Inside python, throwing the exception the way you are saying will also fail the task:

```
raise ValueError('This will exit bash with an error.')
```

Comment: Actually throwing an exception in Python script won't fail the BashOperator.